# Problem when coding a carousel, images not showing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel

I try to create a carousel. I have several pictures horizontaly with 0 flex shrink lined up inside a div, so when I click a button, all pictures should move left. However, now I only being able to see the first picture, I wonder if I mess up the css, so each picture has a right invisible part that covered the rest of the images.
`

```
const Slider = () => {
  const bannerPics = [banner1, banner2, banner3];

  const [translateX, setTranslateX] = useState(0);
  const currentWidthRef = useRef();

  const renderPics = bannerPics.map((p, i) => {
    //must have a key in order for animation to work(remount the component)
    return (
      <li key={i} className={styles.slide}>
        <img className={styles.img} src={p} alt="" />
      </li>
    );
  });

  const sliderHandler = () => {
    setTranslateX(currentWidthRef.current.clientWidth);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={currentWidthRef}
        className={styles.banner}
        style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-translateX}px, 0, 0)` }}
      >
        {renderPics}
      </div>
      <button onClick={sliderHandler}>MOVE</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;
```

`CSS:`

```
.banner {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because `banner` is moved away as a whole.

To make this carousel work, you can follow this order:

1. Create a `frame` that wraps `banner`
2. Set `frame` as `overflow: hidden`
3. Map the list of `img` on `banner`
4. Animate `banner` to move

Example: (replaces `return` area in `Slider` component)

```
<div>
  <div className={styles.frame}>
    <div
      ref={currentWidthRef}
      className={styles.banner}
      style={{ transform: `translate3d(${-translateX}px, 0, 0)` }}
    >
      {renderPics}
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onClick={sliderHandler}>MOVE</button>
</div>
```

Example: (add `.frame` and replace `.banner` in CSS file)

```
.frame {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

This should work without much refactoring of existing code, and you can further adjust the value of `translateX` on condition to allow move control of this component.

On a side note, not sure why `translate3d` is used for `transform` here because `translateX` will do the same with less code.

Example:

```
style={{ transform: `translateX(${-translateX}px)` }}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you, setting the overflow on the extra frame fixed the issue